# Why do we need stacks when we already have vectors which are even more powerful?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stack, containers

In C++ STL, Stacks are implemented using container adaptors which rewrite the interface of the Vector class. However, why is it necessary to do the interface rewriting and design a Stack class when there is already the Vector class available? Is it due to cost efficiency i.e. maintaining a stack uses less resources while it could do all necessary jobs?

Comment: Note that `std::stack` is implemented using `std::deque` by default

Comment: More power and more flexibility does not automatically mean better. Restricting what a class does often means safer or clearer code, which is its own measure of "better".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do we need for loops and while loops when we already have goto which is even more powerful? You should adhere to the principle of parsimony - use the least powerful tool that is powerful enough to achieve the desired objective.

If what you need is a stack, take a dependency on the standard library class that provides that functionality, not a more powerful one. It also communicates better to a person reading your code, what you are going to do.

Comment: The "communication" bit is a really good point. If I'm debugging a block of code which declares `std::vector<int> stack`, I can't necessarily assume that the code is treating it strictly as a stack. If it declares `std::stack<int> stack`, I can trust that.

Answer (score 6):

The idea behind the container adaptors was to enforce particular abstract data types on an otherwise open-ended container type. If you have a `std::vector`, it's possible to inadvertently insert/erase/access elements in the middle; but if you have a `std::stack` you know that won't happen. It's similar to `const`: You tell the compiler what restrictions to apply, so that it tells you when you accidentally violate them.

IME, people don't really use `stack` and `queue` very often. `priority_queue` is a little more useful. But in each case, one tends to find the odd special case where you need to break the rules a little, and that means foregoing the overly-principled container adaptors.